How to display Step by Step of proof procedures in beamer
I wanna show students the step by step proof's procedure, I mean that one line displays and then, the next line displays in next beamer. I tend to use \pause, but I failed to add \pause in \begin{proof}. Any suggestion is welcomed.
The code is attached. (it contains much useless \usepackage here and just ignore)
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{118,193,188}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{106,172,150}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{94,150,218}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{RGB}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
%\setbeamercolor{block}{bg=aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!75!black, title=Properties of combinatorial numbers(2)]
$C_{n + 1}^m = C_n^m + C_n^{m - 1} (m,n \in {{\rm N}^*},m \leqslant n) $
\end{tcolorbox}
\pause
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        C_n^m + C_n^{m - 1} & = \frac{{n!}}{{m!\left( {n - m} \right)!}} + \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!\left( {n - \left( {m - 1} \right)} \right)!}} \hfill \\
        & = \frac{{n!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} + \frac{{n!m}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} \hfill \\
        & = \frac{{n!\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} = \frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} \hfill \\
        & = C_{n + 1}^m. 
    \end{split}
\end{equation*} 
\end{proof}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

The output beamer is attached.

Note: The little difference between my question and How to typeset a math proof in beamer that displays line by line is that, the answer of my question is \uncover<+->{}, while that of is
\uncover<2->{.....}
\uncover<3->{.....}
...
\uncover<6->{.....}


@BrightBulb123 Thanks for your mention, it is same actually. I will save your comment so that visitors can review previous (8 years ago) posts.

I've taken out some of your included packages from my preamble, feel free to add them back in. :)
Proposed solution
Use \uncover<...>{}.1
Code
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage[fix-amsmath]{mathtools}  % loads amsmath automatically
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{118,193,188}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{106,172,150}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{94,150,218}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{RGB}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
%\setbeamercolor{block}{bg=aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!75!black, title=Properties of combinatorial numbers(2)]
$C_{n + 1}^m = C_n^m + C_n^{m - 1} (m,n \in {{\rm N}^*},m \leqslant n) $
\end{tcolorbox}
\pause
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \uncover<+->{C_n^m + C_n^{m - 1} & = \frac{{n!}}{{m!\left( {n - m} \right)!}} + \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!\left( {n - \left( {m - 1} \right)} \right)!}} \hfill} \\
        \uncover<+->{& = \frac{{n!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} + \frac{{n!m}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} \hfill} \\
        \uncover<+->{& = \frac{{n!\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} = \frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}{{m!\left( {n - m + 1} \right)!}} \hfill} \\
        \uncover<+->{& = C_{n + 1}^m.}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Images


1 Answer to How to typeset a math proof in beamer that displays line by line

Thanks for your answer and mention!
